# C# classes generated from XSD contains properties marked with different qualification attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I cannot understand why C# code generators (xsd, xsd2code) produce output class *Profile* with two properties of the same type marked with different attributes. One of them is marked as *Unqualified* and one is not.

My XSD looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.acme.com" xmlns="http://www.acme.com" elementFormDefault="unqualified">   
  <xsd:complexType name="ParameterList">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="Parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ParameterItem">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="Parameters" type="ParameterList" />
  <xsd:element name="Parameter" type="ParameterItem" />  
  <xsd:element name="Profile">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>        
        <xsd:element ref="Parameters" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="Parameters" type="ParameterList" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>       
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>   
 </xsd:schema>
```

And output code generated by xsd2code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SO2_installation
{
    public class ParameterList
    {
        public ParameterList()
        {
            Parameter = new List<ParameterItem>();
        }

        public List<ParameterItem> Parameter { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParameterItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profile
    {
        public Profile()
        {
            Parameters1 = new List<ParameterItem>();
            Parameters = new List<ParameterItem>();
        }

        [XmlArray(Order = 0)]
        [XmlArrayItem("Parameter", IsNullable = false)]
        public List<ParameterItem> Parameters { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Parameters", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 1)]
        [XmlArrayItem("Parameter", IsNullable = false)]
        public List<ParameterItem> Parameters1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code has been simplified by R#, so it's not exact output from the xsd2code, but it shows what bothers me - why the two properties are not marked with the same attributes?

This is a problem while preparing XML file that corresponds with the XSD. It should look like this one below, which makes the preparation very error prone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                      
<Profile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Parameters xmlns="http://www.acme.com">    
        <Parameter xmlns="http://www.acme.com">
            <Name xmlns="">SERIALNUMBER</Name>
            <Value xmlns="">600001</Value>
        </Parameter>        
    </Parameters>       
    <Parameters1 xmlns="">  
        <Parameter xmlns="http://www.acme.com">
            <Name xmlns="">SERIALNUMBER</Name>
            <Value xmlns="">600002</Value>
        </Parameter>        
    </Parameters1>          
</Profile>
```

The answer to the question: "why two properties of the same type, based on the same xsd are marked with different attributes" is not my main concern. As I cannot change XSD files (they were sent to the clients a long time ago), I need to find a way to consume XML files regardless whether their elements are marked with namespaces or not. Currently, when I pass XML with, for example:

```
<Parameters1 xmlns="http://www.acme.com">
```

*XmlSerializer* will return a parsing error. It would be nice to sent XML with all parameters marked with the namespace, or without the namespace - doesn't matter as long as they would be marked consistently.

Thank you in advance for helping me with this issue.

Additional note: the example is prepared to simplify the attached code, so please don't care that *Profile* consists of two properties of the same kind.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why two properties are generated is:

```
elementFormDefault="unqualified">
```

which means that all LOCAL elements in XML should not be qualified - should be qualified with empty namespace xmlns="". In other words in the given code fragment:

```
<xsd:element name="Profile">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>        
        <xsd:element ref="Parameters" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="Parameters" type="ParameterList" minOccurs="1" 
           maxOccurs="1"/>       
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
```

First element Parameters is a reference to GLOBAL type which in XML should be qualified with target namespace. Why? Because all global elements should be qualified with target namespace no matter what is the value of the attribute elementFormDefault.

Second element is a LOCAL definition of new Parameters element and since elementFormDefault="unqualified" in XML which will be validated with this xsd there are two obligatory elements Parameteres, qualified with different namespaces.

To fully answer your question - I can't see a solution without changing or overriding definitions in your xsd. If Paramters elements in your original xsd has attribute minOccurs="0" it is possible to omit them. Maybe redefinition is also an option for your business case (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_redefine.asp).